# JMeter enable/disable HTTP Request Sampler upon certain condition

Tags: jmeter, httprequest

I have a few HTTP Request Samplers that I would only like to execute when a certain condition has been met. What I have done is added a BeanShell PreProcessor to the HTTP Request Sampler with the following code

```
if (${getTeamName}.equals("Test Team") == true)
{
    HTTPSampler.setEnabled(false);
}
```

If the value of getTeamName is **Test Team** then I want to disable that HTTP Request Sampler, as it doesn't have to be executed then. However it looks like that currently doesn't work.

Is there any one who knows what I'm doing wrong here, or a suggestion to what I should do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) guide:

> But of course ensure your script is necessary and efficiently written, **DON'T OVERSCRIPT**

Why not just to use [If Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) like:

- If Controller, condition: `"${getTeamName}" != "Test Team"`

  - HTTP Request Sampler

If `${getTeamName}` will be `Test Team` child sampler(s) won't be executed.

Comment: Yes, if controller would be nicer & readable. However, `sampler.setEnabled(false)` does not seem to work. I never tried this before. What is the use of this method?

Comment: Thanks, this works great. It only executes the HTTP Request Sampler now when it has to execute it.

Answer (score 1):

While using beanshell, access variables using `vars.get("VARNAME")`

```
if (vars.get("getTeamName").equals("Test Team") == true)
{
     sampler.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the sampler still doesn't seem to get disabled when the name equals "Test Team". I have also tried setting getTeamName as a property and then used if (${__property(getTeamName)}.equals("Test Team") == true)

Comment: @YvesMertens, sorry that i did not know exactly what you were trying to do.  I will go with `If Controller` as DmitriT says for your requirement.

Comment: No problem, it's possible that my question wasn't written that clear to understand. Thanks for trying! Yeah I've tried DmitriT's suggestion and it works.